# Sorting data alphabetically from database

Tags: php, sorting, routes

I have a website with categories. But when I add new categories the last one I have added goes to the back of the list. That is not a problem but I would like to sort them alphabetically on the frontend.

Here is my code;

```
              <div class="card-body pr-0 pl-0">
            <ul class="category-list-custom">
              @foreach($categories as $category)
              <li>
                <a href="{{ route('article.category.list',['category' => $category['category']->slug]) }}">{{ $category['category']->name }} <span></span></a>
                @if(!empty($category['sub']))

                  <ul>

                      @foreach($category['sub'] as $subcategory)
                      <li><a href="{{ route('article.subcategory.list',['category' => $category['category']->slug,'subcategory' => $subcategory->slug]) }}">{{ $subcategory->name }}</a></li>
                      @endforeach

                  </ul>

                @endif
              </li>
              @endforeach
            </ul>
```

Thank you very much for your help!

EDIT:

I am new at this and sorry for the trouble. :)

Comment: I'm guessing you're fetching them from a database? In that case, the easiest way would be to add an `ORDER BY theColumnName ASC` in your query when you fetch them.

Comment: I am very sorry but I am new at this and I do really try hard, could you please direct me some more to how and where could I do this?

Comment: You never answered if you're using a database or not. Post the code that fetches the categories and populates the `$categories` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Use the ORDER BY sql function when retrieving your categories from the database. Follow this format:

```
SELECT categories, ...
FROM table_name
ORDER BY categoryname, column2, ... ASC|DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you retrieve this categories from database, you could add this line to your query

```
ORDER BY name ASC
```